# How to send sortable list values with form that contain other inputs using php

Tags: php, list, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable orderd list inside a form that user sort it then fill some input fields in the form then submit the form . i am using php and jquery sortable plugin.. how can i send the list with the other form values or drop the sortable items in a textarea any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I solved the problem:
I used  `draggable="true"` with all list items then i used the following javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', event.target.innerHTML+"\n");
    });
```

after that user can drag any list item and drop it in the textarea

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery UI sortable feature have [serialize method](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) which is so easy to use
Here's a quick example that sends the data to the specified URL as soon as an element has changes position:

```
  $('#your-ulelement').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'any url for get data'
        });
    }
});
```

then you can use it in PHP as an array easily